# Manga about a boy being visited by the ghost of his deceased girlfriend

Tags: story-identification, manga, ghost

I'm looking for a manga where the protagonist's girlfriend dies, and he is later visited by three ghosts of her; one from the past, one from the present and one from the future.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, was it set in the present day?